# altair not compatible with pandas: module 'pandas.core' has no attribute

Tags: python, pandas, visualization, altair

I recently started using `altair` but was never able to make it work.

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

print(pd.__version__)   #1.0.5
print(alt.__version__)  #2.0.0rc1 

source = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'],
    'b': [28, 55, 43, 91, 81, 53, 19, 87, 52]
})

alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x='a',
    y='b'
)
```

Gives me the errors:

```
/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/altair/utils/core.py in sanitize_dataframe(df)
     77     df = df.copy()
     78 
---> 79     if isinstance(df.index, pd.core.index.MultiIndex):
     80         raise ValueError('Hierarchical indices not supported')
     81     if isinstance(df.columns, pd.core.index.MultiIndex):

AttributeError: module 'pandas.core' has no attribute 'index'
```

Some time ago I might have tried to install an extension to make `altair` work with JupyterLab. I don't think there's anything else I did to screw it up.

Any suggestions on how shall I make it work?

Comment: I copy/pasted your code into my notebook and it worked perfectly. I am using Altair 4.1.0, that's the only difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altair's current release is version 4.1; it has a large number of improvements and bug fixes since version 2.0, and this is one of them. If you update Altair to a recent release, it should work.